# How to find files of the form $INPUTDIR/*/*/*/results.txt in C++ ( Linux )

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am trying to make a vector of filenames of the form `$INPUTDIR/*/*/*/results.txt`
or in other words find all files of the name `results.txt` at a depth of 3 from the given INPUT_DIRECTORY.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at the man page for the `glob()` function - this does exactly what you need.

Comment: Or you could use the hideously bloated `wordexp` interface to accomplish both at the same time...